# Storing a document in a remote server file system using PHP and ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I've been trying to create a program that allows me to send files to my remote server(php backend) from my local environment. The programme also stores infomation about the uploaded file in a Mysql DB. After doing some research I'm convinced that storing the documents on the file system is the way to go.

The ajax side of my code seems to send the data properly, but when the form data(including the file) are being processed by the php code, the database entry is made but the file isn't uploaded. I've tried `var_dump([$_FILES])` and I can see the file array with all information but the file isnt getting stored.

this is my ajax code

```
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/api/document/create.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

and this is my PHP code

```
var_dump([$_FILES]);

$uploads_dir = './uploaded';

$tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
```

Also I've come across sites that mention using cURL, I'm wondering is theres a way of achieving this without using cURL, and if so, How?

Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: cURL won't help you in this case.

Comment: First stop you _also_ need to consider in such cases is: _what does your http servers error log file tell you_? This most likely is a file system permission issue on the server side.

Comment: check upload_max_filesize , post_max_size and file_upload values in php ini and directory has proper permission or not.

Comment: Look at [the return values section of the function you are using](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file)

Comment: Consider if the user running the webserver has the correct access rights to write in the final folder `$upload_dirs` (I also hope that this folder does exist)

Comment: firstly handle the exceptions which will help you to get proper details where the error is http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: "If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued." (http://php.net/move_uploaded_file). You aren't even checking whether this operation succeeds.

Comment: @arkascha thank you. It was an issue with file permissions, after i granted permission, everything worked fine.